# How do you turn a string back into an array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Firstly is there a way to turn a string into an array?
I'm looking for a way to turn this:

```
['[[ 18.41978673]\n', ' [  0.34748864]\n', ' [ -9.55729142]]']
```

back into

```
[[ 18.41978673]
 [  0.34748864]
 [ -9.55729142]]
```

Secondly, is there a was to store the array as an array in a .txt file without having to turn it into a string in the first place?
This is the current method I have been using to put them into storage:

```
def add_to_file(self, weights):
    path = 'C:/Users\PycharmProjects\project Current'
    file = open(path, 'w')
    file.write(weights)
    file.close()

add_to_file(str(synaptic_weights))
```

When trying to do it the following way:

```
add_to_file(synaptic_weights)
```

I have this return in the console:

> TypeError: write() argument must be str, not numpy.ndarray

The file type doesn't have to be .txt. If there is a better way to store arrays I am all ears.

Comment: Have a look at `serializing` https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

Comment: Use [`numpy.save`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.save.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to jump through a few hoops, but you can do it with `json.loads` and `re.sub`. This is the first step to salvaging your data and storing it in a usable form.

```
import json
import re

data = json.loads(re.sub(r"'|\\n", '', str(l)))[0]
print(data)
# [[18.41978673], [0.34748864], [-9.55729142]]
```

---

Now that you've salvaged your data, you can look at some options for saving to a file.

One option (probably the best) is using [`np.save`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html):

```
np.save('data.npy', data)
```

Alternatives include either  `json.dump` or `pickle.dump`. This would work:

```
import json
json.dump(data, open('data.json', 'w'))
```

Or, with `pickle`:

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(data, open('data.pkl', 'wb'))
```

Comment: Of course this works, but if he'd serialize it in the first place it would be much better.

Comment: @moritzg The list has not been stringified properly to begin with. If OP is to salvage anything, sooner or later, they'd need to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using a Numpy array, an easy solution to save the array is:

```
np.savetxt(file_name, my_array)
```

then:

```
my_array = np.loadtxt(file_name)
```

Comment: There's a typo there, the function is called [`np.savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html), not `np.savetext`.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use

```
a = np.ones((3,3))
np.save('arr', a)

a2 = np.load('arr.npy')
print a2
```

See the documentation here: [np.save](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html), [np.load](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html)